# Local Npm module "..\..\node_modules\cssmin" not found. Is it installed?

Tags: gruntjs, typescript, durandal, rubymine

I use durandaljs + typescript + gruntjs to programming at RubyMine environment. But after I click the "run" button in the Gruntfile.js, it always show

```
Local Npm module "..\..\node_modules\cssmin" not found. Is it installed?
```

However, my project seems still good to go. How to eliminate the above warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cssmin` is probably used at deploy time and therefore you aren't getting runtime errors yet. Fix : `npm install cssmin --saveDev` from the same directory as `gruntfile.js`